# construct a sequence in $\delta$-ring from a sequence in $\sigma$-ring.

Tags: analysis

Let $S$ be a non empty set, $\mathcal{P}$ be the $\delta$-ring of subsets of $S$ and $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{P})$  the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal{P}$. Consider the function $f$ defined on $S$ with values in a Banach space $X$. I have constructed a sequence $\{\phi_n \}$ which converges to $f$  defined as $$\phi_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\chi_{A_i},$$ where  $A_i\in \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{P}) $  are disjoint and $x_i\in X$ for every $i$.
Now I want to construct a sequence $\{\psi_n\}$ which converges to $f$ such that $$\psi_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\chi_{B_i},$$ where  $B_i\in \mathcal{P} $ and $y_i \in X$.

We know that each $A\in \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{P})$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint elements of $\mathcal{P}$ and for every $E\in \mathcal{P}$,  $A\cap E \in \mathcal{P}$. I am not sure that  it is possible to construct such sequence or not. If yes then how can we do it? Any kind of suggestion regarding this would be helpful for me. Thank you.